Meaning of phrase "We meet you where you are"?
A local homeless shelter has the following paragraph on their website:

... We accept people unconditionally, and we meet them where they are. People get a chance to really see Christ here, instead of just hear about him or read about him....

In this context, what does the phrase "we meet them where they are" mean? There is confusion from the staff as to what there words mean. So I am trying to get an analysis from a few people who have actual study and credentials in the English language.

I think it's incoherent confused meaningless waffle, presumably intended to mean something like "We accept people on their own terms"  (we don't judge people, or expect them to share our faith). But obviously they don't, since most of the homeless people they're trying to reach aren't Christians, but they will be strongly encouraged to become so in return for food and shelter.

It means...what the words say: "We meet people in the places where they are currently located." The location is, of course, an entirely metaphorical one. Can you clarify what the source of confusion is?

Have you thought about asking the homeless shelter itself?

"We meet them where they are" means we accept people just the way they are. We don't ask them to change or be different. It's like saying, "We are here for you, no matter what." Instead of expecting everyone to believe or act in a certain way, we try to understand where they are coming from and what they are going through.
Rather than making people feel like they have to meet certain rules or standards to fit in, we say, "You are welcome here, just as you are." It's about showing kindness and support, without judging or pushing anyone away. This approach helps create a safe and welcoming environment where people can truly feel accepted and understood for who they are.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
